# Ajax Listen Event on a Button Click then Runs a Php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, button

I need the AJAX to listen to if a button is click. Then if it is I need it to run a PHP script. I am having troubles by the AJAX not correctly listening to the Button Click and so it never runs the script.
Any Error in my code you may see?
Any advice on how I should do this?

The Button:

```
<input id="button_1" type="button" value="favorites1" onclick="favfunct();" />
```

The AJAX that calls it is: (`ajaxlisten.js`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () { // Make sure the elements are loaded on the page
        // Listen for a click event on the button
        $('#button_1').click(favfunct);
    });

    function favfunct(e) {
        // Stop the page from "following" the button (ie. submitting the form)
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // Call an AJAX function to the proper page
        $.ajax("js/addtofavorites.php", {
            // Pass our data to the server
            data: { "get" : "runfunction", "action" : "favorites1" },
            // Pass using the appropriate method
            method: "POST",
            // When the request is completed and successful, run this code.
            success: function (response) {
            // Successfully added to favorites. JS code goes here for this condition.
                alert ("successfully loaded")
            }          
        });
    }
</script>
```

Php File (`addtofavorites.php`)

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","student");

if ($_POST["action"] = 'favorites1')
{ 
    if (!$con);
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }                   
    mysql_select_db("tvid", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO tv (userid, favorites) VALUES (345,77);"
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con));
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Your Video was Added To Your Favorites";
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: There's no `method` property for `$.ajax`. There's `type` which determines whether it's `POST` or `GET`. Anyway, what does it mean that it doesn't "listen correctly"? Are you getting an error of any kind or nothing happens?

Comment: It does not run the addtofavorites.php script. The button does nothing, even though I have referenced it to do something when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting the `click` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#button_1').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        favfunct();
   });
});
```

Then the `favfunct`:

```
function favfunct() {
// AJAX Call Below
// rest of your code
```

That should get your `favfunct` running. After that you can further debug the code if necessary.

You can also take the `onclick` off the button:

```
<input id="button_1" type="button" value="favorites1" />
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sbybd/

Example of `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "js/addtofavorites.php",
     data: { "get" : "runfunction", "action" : "favorites1" },
     success: function (response) {
         alert ("successfully loaded");
     }    
 });
```

Comment: any idea to how to get the AJAX to successfully call upon the Php file to add to the database?

Comment: @JulianNeill You need to write it correctly. Refer to the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information and I updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thank You will look more into it